# SQL Router Not Applying Round Rubin

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-cluster, mysqlrouter

I configure sql router under three machines and found if I use simple command `mysql -u ia -pTest@123 --port=7001` then its not applying round rubin connection request but when i use with protocol parameter then its working fine `"mysql -u ia -pTest@123 --port=7001 --protocol=TCP"`
I want to connect with normal command like mysql -u ia -pTest@123 --port=7001
and round rubin should work in this case.

```
=== Mysql Configuration
[logger]
level = INFO
[routing:secondary]
bind_address = localhost
bind_port = 7001
destinations = 192.168.0.187:3306,192.168.0.190:3306
routing_strategy = round-robin
[routing:primary]
bind_address = localhost
bind_port = 7002
destinations = 192.168.0.186:3306
routing_strategy = first-available (edited)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every connection has a -h 127.0.0.1 or as you have a --protocol=TCP" on local computers to use round-Robin.

The problem is on linux computers mysql tries to open a [socket](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-unix-socket.html) connection, where you can' use Roud-Robin.

The same is true for Windows computers, but there mysql uses [named pipes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-named-pipe.html)

so you have to force the connection to use tcp/ip, that works with an ipadress in -h or like you used forcing the protocol

Comment: you are correct and its working with -h. Is there anyway where we implement same thing without any additional parameter like "mysql -u ia -pTest@123 --port=7001"

Comment: disable sockets which i haven't tried yet https://www.faqforge.com/linux/controlpanels/ispconfig2/configure-mysql-server-use-tcp-connections-instead-of-unix-sockets/  I really can't see that it matters,you have to add always to add one or other option to mysql, so what does it matter, you can write a batch command that includes all options